# Angular modules conflict

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use two modules Angular Strap (http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) and UI Bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Is it possible to use them both in one application. I have issue with dropdown. Do I have  to choose one module or maybe can I inject needed module. In Coach view I use pagination from UI Bootstrap and dropdown - which is broken but I want use Angular Strap dropdown. How to inject this two modules?

**app.js**

```
angular.module('projApp', [
    ....
    'mgcrea.ngStrap',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
```

**controllers/coaches.js**

```
angular.module('projApp').controller('CoachesCtrl', function ($scope, Coach) {
....
```

Answer (score 0):

From the angular bootstrap website, you can create a build where you should not include dropdown if you want to use the one of Angular Strap. Indeed both libraries provide conflicting directives so you need to chose from one or another.

Unfortunately I don't think Angular Strap has a build system, so you'll need to remove a directive manually from the source code if you want to keep the one from angular bootstrap.